# How to create a custom method for the hint parameter of the input method in ActiveAdmin/Simple Form gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring, activeadmin, simple-form

From this code:

```
ActiveAdmin.register News do

  form do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :url
      f.input :site_name
      f.input :site_url
      f.input :image,
              as: :file,
              hint: if f.object.image_url
                      f.template.image_tag(f.object.image_url)
                    else
                      ''
                    end
    end
    f.actions
  end
end
```

I want to extract the `if` clause in a method, since I have this part repeating a lot. The question is - how exactly do I do that? To clarify:

1. Where do I define the method - in some helper, in a new file? How do I make sure ActiveAdmin has access to this file? Do I have to create a custom ActiveAdmin controller action?
2. Although something like `some_method(f, field)` (`field` is in my case `image`) is acceptable, I would like to have it in a more generic form, so that I repeat myself less, like `f.hint` with the `hint` method inferring the `field` name as the first parameter of `f.input`. Is this possible?

Any advice on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way would be to simply [create your own formtastic input](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic#modified--custom-inputs) for images that either set the hint option by default, or add in extra HTML to show an image preview. Doing so might allow you to do something like this:

```
f.input :image, as: :image, preview: f.object.image_url
```